# ServiceNow WSDL Timezone needs to change to Users timezone

Tags: web-services, wsdl, timezone, servicenow

From Servicenow WSDL, am getting data in some time-zone format. 
In Servicenow, there is a option to change the users timezone and get the data as expected . But if we change the timezone in servicenow, it didnt affect for the data which comes through servicenow-WSDL.

How to convert the timezone for the data get through WSDL. Is there any way available in servicenow to automatically convert ? or any idea to develope our own script/code to do the same?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you include more details regarding the request you are making to ServiceNow's SOAP Web Services? - What type of a request are you making (e.g., getRecords)? - What field(s) are returning time zone information? - What is the time zone setting of the user account you are using to make the Web Services call?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes . Am calling servicenows soap webservices. & getRecords. In Incident.wsdl, it return only the sys_created_on,sys_updated_on ..etc like date columns. It didnt give any timezone info. Am set CST(central) timezone for the account .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to keep in mind when working with SN web services is that by default all time values will come back in UTC time. You can ask for "Display Values" by setting request parameter "displayValue" to either "true" to get back only display values or "all" to get back both display values and direct values.

The Display value for a time field is resolved according to: user timezone preference, then by system timezone.

For example, you could get the WSDL with this request:

```
https://<instance>.service-now.com/incident.do?WSDL&displayValue=true
```

and then also include the &displayValue=true on the SOAP request:

```
https://<instance>.service-now.com/incident.do?SOAP&displayValue=true
```

Here's a link to the product docs with more info about getting back display values through SOAP: http://wiki.servicenow.com/?title=Direct_Web_Services#Return_Display_Value_for_Reference_Variables

Note the same rules apply when using the REST interface as well, but the parameter is "sysparm_display_value" (http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API).

Hope this helps.